# function GetURLParameter(sParam) is returning %20 as white space on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this code that pulls the URL parameter into the landing page, the issue is it is pulling white space in as %20. So if my url parameter is:
example.com/?title=my website   it wil display my%20website on the page i want it to display my website without the %20. Here is the code

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
   {   
     var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
     var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
     for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
  {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
    {
        return sParameterName[1];
    }
  }
  }

(function ($) {
// fire once DOM is loaded
$(document).ready(function() {
    // set the cookie name
    var cookie_name = 'node-title';
    // get the "phone" URL param
    var phone_number = GetURLParameter('title');
    // check if there is a phone number in the URL
    if (phone_number) {
        // set the cookie
        $.cookie(cookie_name, phone_number, { path: '/' });
    }
    // get the phone cookie value
    var phone_cookie = $.cookie(cookie_name);
    // check if there is a value set in the phone cookie
    if (phone_cookie) {
        // swap the phone number
        $('.' + cookie_name).html(phone_cookie);
        // update the href too
        $('a.' + cookie_name).attr('href', 'tel://' + phone_cookie);
    }
    });
    })(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just url-decode the value before returning.  Replace

```
return sParameterName[1];
```

with

```
return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

The text you are seeing is what's called `url-encoded`. You simply need to decode it before displaying it. You can change your `GetURLParameter()` function to this:

```
function GetURLParameter(sParam)
   {   
     var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
     var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
     for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
  {
    var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
    if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
    {
        return return decodeURIComponent(sParameterName[1]);
    }
  }
}
```

If you are interested in learning more about the different `url-encoded` components, check this link:

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp